# Finding Duplicates Message Box VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, large-data

The code I currently have below is fast and efficient for finding duplicates in column "A". I am working with a very large data set 40-50,000 rows sometimes more. Although this code is good, it will throw an error code if no duplicates are found.

I can circumvent this by removing the "On error go to 0" line but then its will copy paste the whole data set. Is there a way to modify this code to display a msg box if no duplicates are found?

If not maybe a separate Sub that will call this Sub if duplicates are found and if not display an message box? Although many are not efficient enough for a large data set.

```
Sub filtersort()

  Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
  Dim arr(), x, dict, arrOut()

  With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With

  Set wsData = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  On Error Resume Next
  Set wsOutput = Sheets("Duplicate Data")
  wsOutput.Cells.Clear
  On Error GoTo 0

  If wsOutput Is Nothing Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=wsData).Name = "Duplicate Data"
    Set wsOutput = ActiveSheet
  End If
  LastRow = wsData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  LastCol = wsData.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

  Set Rng = wsData.Range("A3:A" & LastRow)

  x = wsData.Range("A4:V" & LastRow).Value
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If Not dict.exists(x(i, 1)) Then
      dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
    Else
      j = j + 1
      ReDim Preserve arr(1 To j)
      arr(j) = x(i, 1)
    End If
  Next i

  ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(x, 1), 1 To UBound(x, 2))
  For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(x(i, 1), arr, 0)) Then
      n = n + 1
      For j = 1 To UBound(x, 2)
        arrOut(n, j) = x(i, j)
      Next j
    End If
  Next i

  wsData.Range("A3:V3").Copy wsOutput.Range("A3")

  wsOutput.Range("A4").Resize(n, UBound(x, 2)).Value = arrOut

  LastRow = wsOutput.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  wsOutput.Range("A3:V" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=wsOutput.Range("A4"), 
  Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
  With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Two solutions come to my mind. (1) `dict.Count` should give you the number of items added to the dictionary, possibly zero or, if that can't be done, throw an error if it is zero. (2) Create a variable Boolean with a name like `FoundDuplicate` and set that variable to True whenever a duplicate is added to the dictionary.

Comment: @Variatus second approach is safer and straightforward.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself? I'm just curious as to why you do the `Dictionary.Exists` check and then the `Application.Match` check. Isn't that checking for a duplicate twice? There might be some efficiency gains available to you.

Comment: I have not used the Boolaean method much.. Would I do something along the lines of "If dict.count.value > 1 then "apply my code" Else end if msg box"? @Ambie And no I had some help. Any sugestions to make it more efficient would be great.

Comment: No, just `If dict.Count > 0` indicates that there are values in the dictionary. Boolean is a data type, like String or Integer but it knows only True and False. So, you set `FoundDuplicate = True` when you found a duplicate and later ask `If FoundDuplicate = True Then` and else do nothng.

Comment: Do you want each duplicate listed only once?  Or, if there are multiple duplicates, do you want each duplicate listed?

Comment: If there are multiple duplicates, then I want each duplicate listed.

Comment: Another method, not involving VBA (although you could record a macro), would be to use the Advanced Filter.  You could use a formula criteria similar to `=countif($A$3:$A$n,$A3) > 1` and copy results to a different range.  If you used a table and structured references, you could easily refer to the entire data column, and the range reference would auto adjust.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the collection or the filter method would be faster on a large data set, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced your code is as efficient as you think. There are a number of ways of finding duplicates: one is to use a `Dictionary` or `Collection` object which can only accept unique values as its key; another is to call the `Application.Match` function and test for a positive result. Your code appears to do both, so you might be better off picking one or the other. The sample code below uses a `Dictionary` as it also answers the question about testing it for any duplicates.

There is also quite a lot of redundant code in your post. `LastCol`, `Rng`, etc. which are never used.

If you can, it's good to avoid incrementally redimming your arrays too. Given that you know the size of your dictionary of unique values then the `Redim` can be done just once.

You can test if any duplicates exist by exploiting the `.Count` property of your `Dictionary` - again, shown in the code below.

So, here's one way your code could work:

**Update**

Adjustments from your comment. Main difference is that testing for duplicates is done using a Boolean flag, but also picks up first and last dupes.

```
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim keyRefs As Object, dupes As Object
Dim keyF As String, keyL As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim data As Variant, output() As Variant, r As Variant
Dim dupesFound As Boolean

'Set application values temporarily.
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Assign worksheet object.
Set wsData = Worksheets("Sheet1")
On Error Resume Next
Set wsOutput = Sheets("Duplicate Data")
On Error GoTo 0
If Not wsOutput Is Nothing Then
    wsOutput.Cells.Clear
Else
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=wsData).Name = "Duplicate Data"
    Set wsOutput = ActiveSheet
End If

'Read data into array.
With wsData
    data = .Range(.Cells(4, "A"), _
           .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) _
           .Resize(, 23).Value2
End With

'Gather the non-duplcate index numbers.
Set keyRefs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dupes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
    keyF = CStr(data(i, 1))
    If Not keyRefs.Exists(keyF) Then
        keyRefs.Add keyF, i
    Else
        If Not dupesFound Then dupesFound = True
        keyL = CStr(data(i, 1)) & "|L"
        If Not dupes.Exists(keyF) Then
            dupes.Add keyF, keyRefs(keyF)
            dupes.Add keyL, i
        Else
            dupes(keyL) = i
        End If
    End If
Next

'Read each unique index from data array to output array,
'and write to sheet.
If dupesFound Then 'this tests if you have any duplicates
    ReDim output(1 To dupes.Count, 1 To UBound(data, 2))
    i = 1
    For Each r In dupes.items
        For j = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            output(i, j) = data(r, j)
        Next
        i = i + 1
    Next
    With wsOutput
        .Range("A3:V3").Value = wsData.Range("A3:V3").Value2
        .Range("A4").Resize(UBound(output, 1), UBound(output, 2)).Value = output
        With .Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=wsOutput.Range("A3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange wsOutput.Range("A3").Resize(UBound(output, 1) + 1, UBound(output, 2))
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "No duplicates found."
End If

'Reset application values.
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but for some reason when testing your method only the unique values appear on the duplicate page and the last instance of the duplicate is removed. In addition, if there are no duplicates,  the "Duplicate Data" sheet will just populate with all the original data and the message box does not appear. I am just looking for the first and last instants of duplicates to appear on the "Duplicate Data" Sheet and if there happens to be non then have the message box appear.

Comment: Ah, okay, I misunderstood your task. Code is now adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked but my free [Duplicate Master addin](https://stackexchange.com/users/321941/brettdj) is optimsed for arrays and goes beyond normal duplicate functionality

[image]